# Url route in codeigniter notworking

Tags: codeigniter, url, routes

application/config/routes.php

```
       $route['aboutus'] = 'footerpage/index/$2';
```

Url route concept is not working in codeigniter.
Here try i to change the url footerpage/index/1 into aboutus

Url is like

```
        http:local.com/footerpage/index/1
```

want to be like this

```
       http:local.com/aboutus
```

Comment: Does the rest of your routing work correctly for the site?

Comment: where does `1` come from in `local.com/footerpage/index/1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this ?

```
$route['footerpage/index/[0-9]+'] = "aboutus";
```

I assumed that the number after index will vary ... but you can change `[0-9]+` to `1` if doesn't change value like this

```
$route['footerpage/index/1'] = "aboutus";
```

hope that helps

Comment: add a slash  before aboutus  like so $route['footerpage/index/1'] = "/aboutus";

Answer (score 0):

just use .htaccess, like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.local.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
Redirect 301 /footerpage/index/1 /aboutus
```

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding 1 is id from database and it will not change, so in your controller "footerpage" and "index" function u can give id as 1 directly...no need to define id in routes

in routes

```
$route['aboutus'] = 'footerpage/index';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$route['aboutus/(:any)'] = 'footerpage/index/$2';
```

The uri would show the parmaeter passed as a variable to the controller.